# Downloading Google Earth API Library

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-earth-plugin

Is it possible to download and host the Google Earth API JS Library? I have some pages and Chrome Extensions based on it and I don't want to migrate to the WebGL Google Maps API or Cesium HTML5 platforms. I would at least like to keep some legacy support. Should I go through the script and download all the referenced files and modify the script to use the downloaded one or is there a download-ready version out there?

Answer (score 1):

There is more to the Earth API than just some JavaScript code. You also need the Google Earth Plugin which depends on [NPAPI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NPAPI).

The current version 42 of Chrome has disabled NPAPI by default, and version 45, due out later this year, will remove NPAPI support completely.

The only practical plan at this point is to start investigating your other options.